# Systemd: Type=forking vs. PIDFile

Tags: systemd, rhel

After the Unix admins enabled the `systemd --user` for our application's account, I created the following service-template (itself generated from an Ansible-template first, as you may notice -- because systemd-version on RHEL7 does not understand the `%H` yet):

```
[Unit]
Description=%i Secondary Services

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=%h/apps/%i
{% set ICODE = ansible_hostname | upper %}
ExecStartPre=test -d %h/apps/%i/adco/datafiles
ExecStart=/bin/bash ./launchapp /INSTALLATION_CODE:{{ ICODE }}
ExecStop=/bin/bash ./launchapp /INSTALLATION_CODE:{{ ICODE }} -k
Type=forking
PIDFile=%h/apps/%i/logs/{{ ICODE }}.pid
Restart=always
RestartSec=7
StartLimitBurst=0
Nice=7
TimeoutSec=3593
```

Using this, we were able to create several services -- one for every instance of the application on the shared servers. This worked for about two months, until the OS-patching last week.

After the patching, the services would continuously restart -- on all of the patched machines. Not because there is anything wrong with our application (which hasn't changed), but because the `systemd --user` process itself restarts.

Our Unix-support folks, tried to understand *why* and could not -- all it logs is "restarting", according to them (RHEL being what it is, a mortal cannot read `/var/log/messages` himself -- it requires root).

While they are trying to understand, what's going on, I commented out the `Type=forking` line -- and the restarts stopped! `systemctl --user status` lists all services: from the `systemd --user` down to the multiple instances of the above template.

The questions:

1. What could be wrong with our `systemd --user` itself -- that was continuously restarting? The launched application is heavy on resources, starting about 40 sizeable processes. But that was never a problem before... Perhaps, there is a limit on the number of processes launched by `systemd --user`? Or their combined memory use? Why weren't we hitting it before, if so?
2. Why would commenting out the `Type`-line help?
3. What's the cost of this commenting out -- will `systemd`, for example, still notice, if the master-process (that, whose PID is recorded in the PID-file) goes away? Will it still bring the application-instance up on reboot?